# Is is possible to use an IF in mysql subquery?

Tags: mysql

Trying to check if a name exists (in another table) and add to insert query in one step. I've discovered if the submitted empNum isn't in the User database, the query errors with: Column 'lastName' cannot be null. Can an if statement be used in the subquery something like below?

```
INSERT INTO Password_Reset (empNum, lastName, fromIP, dateReset)
    VALUES (34567, 
    IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User WHERE empNum = 34567, SELECT lastName FROM User WHERE empNum = 34567, '---'),
    '192.168.1.1',
    NOW())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subqueries should be in parenthesis :

```
IF( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User WHERE empNum = 34567), 
    (SELECT lastName FROM User WHERE empNum = 34567), 
 '---'),
```

There many other ways you can do the same as already mentioned by others, but your version will also work after adding required "()".

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, your best bet is to use the [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) operator.

```
INSERT INTO Password_Reset (empNum, lastName, fromIP, dateReset)
    VALUES (34567, 
    COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User WHERE empNum = 34567, SELECT lastName FROM User WHERE empNum = 34567), '---'),
    '192.168.1.1',
    NOW())
```

The [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function could be used, but it would be much more verbose:

```
INSERT INTO Password_Reset (empNum, lastName, fromIP, dateReset)
    VALUES (34567, 
    IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User WHERE empNum = 34567, SELECT lastName FROM User WHERE empNum = 34567) IS NOT NULL, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM User WHERE empNum = 34567, SELECT lastName FROM User WHERE empNum = 34567), '---'),
    '192.168.1.1',
    NOW())
```

Comment: The COALESCE returns a syntax error at `'SELECT lastName FROM...'`

Answer (score 0):

you could use a case:

```
INSERT INTO Password_Reset (empNum, lastName, fromIP, dateReset)
SELECT 
    34567,
    CASE (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM User WHERE empNum = 34567))
        WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT lastName FROM User WHERE empNum = 34567)
        ELSE '---'
    END,
    '192.168.1.1',
    NOW()
```